# Documentation for the Prolog dialect Prova

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I would like to switch from SWI-Prolog to [Prova](https://prova.ws/) - but it seems to be harder than expected:

Predicates like `succ()` are not available and operations like `Var1+Var2>Var3` do not work (obviously it has to be `Var3<Var1+Var2` to be valid).

Is there documentation available describing the differences between Prolog dialects?

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Update #2 (9/2019):

- Most recent User Guide is from 2006 and [can be found here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277296248_PROVA_20_User's_Guide_PROVA_Java_Rule_Language_for_Information_Integration_and_Semantic_Agents_Version_20_User's_Guide)
- The [prova.ws](http://prova.ws) website unfortunately, appears to be down, it used to have ample information. You may try the Wayback machine, but I couldn't find a good copy
- A [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220774155_Prova_Rule-Based_Java_Scripting_for_Distributed_Web_Applications_A_Case_Study_in_Bioinformatics) linked from the [Wikipedia article on Prova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prova) may provide more information, it appears to have syntax examples
- A PDF version of the same seems to be [freely available here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277296248_PROVA_20_User's_Guide_PROVA_Java_Rule_Language_for_Information_Integration_and_Semantic_Agents_Version_20_User's_Guide)

I didn't find a page the specifically shows the differences in the dialects.

---

Original answer was:

The only "Prolog dialects comparison" article I could find is [this ACM article](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=24903). Unfortunately, it is not free. And I'm unsure whether it includes a comparison with Prova.

If Prova is a Java way of doing Prolog, it'll be adjusted to the OO environment of the imperative Java language. It seems to present you with a subset of Prolog, but the syntax is indeed clearly different. The upside is that you can mix "Prolog" with "Java".

You may also look up information about Mandarax, which is Prova compatible to a large extend, but you're probably already aware of that.

Comment: I doubt that this article from 1987 covers the Java-based Prova...
As far as I know Prova is built on Mandarax.

Comment: Yes, Prova is a *Mandarax implementation* for *managing derivation rules in Java in a Prologish way*. I didn't check the date, sorry. I'm afraid there isn't much available then.

Comment: The comparison is not only outdated but also does not mention state-of-the-art systems as of 1987.  In particular Quintus, SICStus, Mu, IF, (X)SB are unmentioned. And the ISO standardization process that started that very same year.

Comment: @false, Six years since my post (!), I can't really recall. But feel free to edit it to make it somewhat more useful.

Comment: @Abel: Someone voted to close it. That's how I found it :-)

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: @TransfiniteNumbers, I've update the links, but it seems the site and pages have been discontinued. Feel free to update if you can find something more useful on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the prova.ws site is discontinued and with it, it seems that the Prova upgrade was discontinued.

---

Original answer:

There is now a lot of documentation available at http://www.prova.ws/documentation.php. The new version is firmly on the way, so both the User's Guide and the Confluence WIKI are very actively progressing. Oh, and the new version is now NOT based on Mandarax, it is a complete rewrite from zero.

Comment: Thank you, this came quite unsuspected.

Comment: Link is broken.